# Linux service "Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'." error while trying to run jar file from automated script?

Tags: linux, shell, service, jar, systemd

I have some scripts to restart a java jar service in linux machine taken from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1171751/restart-systemd-service-automatically-whenever-a-directory-changes-any-file-ins?newreg=2b1573472ca94ce7a093503e29ba3c72)

and here is my *service* script:

```
[Unit]
Description=demo restarter
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=systemctl stop demo.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
StartLimitBurst=0
ExecStartPost=systemctl start demo.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**If I manually add or remove file from the directory it works fine.** But my main purpose is deploying jar file from bitbucket to droplet linux vm and if the file(jar) comes from bitbucket then I get the error:

```
Sep 08 00:09:06 ubuntu-1cpu systemd[1]: Failed to start DEMOOOOOO Spring Boot application service.
Sep 08 00:09:06 ubuntu-1cpu systemd[1]: demo.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 08 00:09:06 ubuntu-1cpu systemd[1]: demo.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Sep 08 00:09:06 ubuntu-1cpu systemd[1]: Failed to start DEMOOOOOO Spring Boot application service.
Sep 08 00:09:06 ubuntu-1cpu systemd[1]: demo.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 08 00:09:06 ubuntu-1cpu systemd[1]: demo.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Sep 08 00:09:06 ubuntu-1cpu systemd[1]: Failed to start DEMOOOOOO Spring Boot application service.
```

I did

```
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
StartLimitBurst=0
```

as suggested in some posts but still I am getting **demo.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.** error.

How can I solve this problem ? (I am suspicious about that when I deploy the jar from bitbucket it is overriding the original jar and maybe it makes problem??)

And here is the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=DEMOOOOOO Spring Boot application service
After=network.target

[Service]
#User=ubuntu
Type=simple
ExecStart=java -jar /root/artifacts2/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

here path file:

```
[Path]
Unit=demo-watcher.service
PathModified=/root/artifacts2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: If the service won't start, changing those parameters won't solve the problem. You need to debug the reason it won't start.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

I have changed `PathModified=` to `PathChanged=` in path script and the problem is solved.